# Concentration of measure and bounds on variance

Tags: pr.probability, oc.optimization-and-control

I am trying to characterize the sensitivity of a function $f: R^N\to{}R$ to the perturbations in the input vector $\mathbb{x}=\left[x_1,\dots{}x_N\right]$. For that purpose, I evaluate Cramer-Rao bound for Gaussian i.i.d. arguments.

The function has a singularity at the point $\mathbb{x}_0$ where $f(\mathbb{x}_0)=0$, in the sense that $\|\nabla{}f\|\sim{}1/f$ as $\mathbb{x}\to\mathbb{x}_0$

The Cramer-Rao bound then doesn't make sense, because it diverges at $\mathbb{x}_0$, while the variance of $f$, obviously, remains bounded. What I am looking for, I guess, some type of "concentration of measure"/"deviation inequality"-type sharp bound on the variance of $f$.

The literature on concentration of measure phenomenon is extensive and deals with fairly advanced topics, whereas I am looking for something rather more basic. If you could point towards some starting point, your help will be appreciated.

Comment: @tristes_tigres The hypothesis that $\|\nabla f(\mathbb{x})\|\to0$ and $f(\mathbb{x})\to0$ with $\|\nabla f(\mathbb{x})\|/f(\mathbb{x})\to1$ when $\mathbb{x}\to0$, is strange. Is this what you wanted to write?

Comment: Didier - I mean that $f(\mathbf{x})=(\nabla{}f)\cdot{(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)}+O((\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)^2)$ near $\mathbf{x}_0$, but my notation was somewhat erroneous. Fixed that.

Comment: The function is defined implicitly, so I mixed different gradients

Comment: @t_t The hypothesis $\|\nabla f\| f\to1$ is even stranger. If you want to say that $f$ is $C^2$ and that $\nabla f(\mathbb{x}_0)=\mathbb{0}$, you could just say so.

Comment: Didier - It's not a hypothesis, it's a property of the specific function that I am analyzing. 

Comment: @t_t My point is that if $f(x_0)=0$ and $\|\nabla f(x)\|\cdot f(x)\to1$ when $x\to x_0$, then $\|\nabla f(x)\|\to+\infty$ when $x\to x_0$. Oh well.

Comment: Didier - this is quite correct, the gradient does go to infinity at $\mathbb{x}_0$. That's what makes the question interesting, because the <b>variation</b> remains bounded. It is qualitativerly clear why, but I would like to produce quantitative bound.


Comment: @t_t I see. Then controlling $E(\|\nabla F\|^2)$ might be an issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_i$ and $X'_i$ be i.i.d random variables.  Write $f = f(X_1, \dots, X_n),$ and define $$f_i = f(X_1, \dots, X'_i, \dots, X_n)$$ as the same function with the $i$th input replaced by the independent copy $X'_i$.

The [**Efron-Stein inequality**](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Publications/PDF/AEifns.pdf) states that $$\operatorname{Var}(f) \le \tfrac 1 2\sum_{i=1}^n \  \mathbb E(f - f_i)^2.$$

Since your random variables are Gaussians, the system satisfies the [**Poincaré inequality**](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~sourav/talk_matrix2.pdf) too: $$\operatorname{Var}(F) \le C \ \mathbb E |\nabla f|^2.$$

Comment: Thank you. I'll need some time to digest the references, and not citing articles behind the paywall is definitely welcome :) 

Comment: I mean, thank you for citing freely accessible articles

Comment: Right off the bat, the trouble with using Poincare inequality is that in my case, $\|\nabla{}f\|\to\infty$ at $\mathbb{x}_0$, so it's hard to see, how to get a useful bound from it. The actual analytic expression for $\mathbb{E}|\nabla{}f|^2$ doesn't seem to be easier to find than that for the $\mathbb{E}|f|^2$


Comment: Although, may be I get, what you mean with Poincare inequality. Perhaps, it could do the job.